# What can cause an app to show "complete an action with" when a button starts an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have a splash activity which is also the launcher, a main menu activity, a sub menu activity, and a description activity.

When I start my app the splash.java loads and then starts the main_menu intent.
The main_menu intent displays a button; this button then starts the sub_menu intent which displays a different button that starts the description intent.

However, when I click that first button on the "main_menu" android displays a prompt asking to "complete action with" and displays two duplicate names of my app, one works and the other does not.

Also, I only get the prompt on the main_menu activity and not on the sub_menu activity.

Any theories/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several intent-filters for activities that can process a fired intent then you'll receive this kind of dialog. This means that the fired intent can be processed by several activities (for instance, you can have several image viewers installed in the system and, thus, when you fire an intent to open an image this dialog will appear and ask you which activity you want to open to process this intent)